# How can I use MPS files in Concert technology using C++

Tags: cplex

I would like to run some benchmarks using MPS files with CPLEX. Is there any method to use MPS files in CPLEX Concert technology with C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `IloCplex` class use [importModel](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex.html#method_importModel):

```
public void importModel(IloModel & m, const char * filename) const
```